Webgl, framebuffer and texture color not render
I'm trying to create two textures, one for depth and one for color, but when I associate the depth texture with the framebuffer and render, the color texture comes up empty, why does this happen?
const createFramebufferWithTexture = () => {
    const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_depth_texture');
    if (!ext) {
        console.error('WEBGL_depth_texture not found');
       // return;
    }

    const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    const depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);

    const error = gl.getError();
    if (error !== gl.NO_ERROR) {
        console.error('Error create depth texture:', error);
     //   return;
    }

    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);

    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        console.error("Framebuffer error", gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER));
    }
    
  //  gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0])

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

    return [fb, targetTexture, depthTexture];
};


My guess is that you forgot to clear the depth texture. Since you neither initialized nor cleared it, its content is undefined, but in reality, it's probably all zeroes. When the GPU performs the depth test, it compares 0 with the actual depth, so the depth test will fail for all pixels. If this is not the case, please create a minimal reproducible example to make it easier to find out what the problem is.
